# Electron CRA app returns blank screen after redirect to /signin

Tags: reactjs, electron, create-react-app, electron-builder

I am working on an electron project with Create react app. The app works fine in dev.
When I package the app with electron-builder, I am able to login to the user account. However, when I logout and redirect to the /signin route, I get a blank screen. When I check the network tab, I get the error that /signin file is not found.

The build section of my package.json

```
"files": [
      "build/**/**/*",
      {
        "from": "dist/src",
        "to": "src",
        "filter": [
          "**/**/*"
        ]
      },
      "node_modules/**/*",
      "./main.js"
    ],
```

The main.js file

```
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');

const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
    },
  });

  const startUrl =
    process.env.ELECTRON_START_URL ||
    url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, './build/index.html'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes: true,
    });

  mainWindow.loadURL(startUrl);
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});
app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

require('./src/server/helpers/ipcMainHandler.js');
```

**I am using hashrouter for routing.**

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved. I figured out the logout method was set to redirect using `window.location.href`.

I passed history as an argument to the logout function and used the push method to get it working.